# Is there a way to open all the links on a webpage into its own tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm doing some QA testing for a website I'm developing and I want to be able to open all the links on the webpage into its own tabs. Right now I have to click on each one manually to open it in a new tab. Is there a trick or plugin to do this automatically and open all the links in a the webpage into their own tab in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that by simply specifying the target attribute in you code i.e. `<a href="link" target="_blank">some text to describe link goal...</a>` this will open the link in a new blank tab.

Comment: i want to open ALL of the links on the page without needing to click on each one.

Comment: The Chrome extension Linkclump could be worth installing,